# Default Activity not found.. how is default activity defined?

Tags: android

How exactly is default activity defined?
As far as I can tell, adding "andriod.intent.action.MAIN" to AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<application
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN/>
```

That should define .MainActivity as the default activity, but it's not working. I've also tried adding the full package name com.package.MainActivity but that's also not working.

This is probably caused by my layout setup, I'm trying to define a layout dynamically in code... here's my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mainlao">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I define my TextureView layout in onCreate here:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlao);
    mButton = new Button(this);
    mButton.setText("pic");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    layout.addView(mTextureView);
    layout.addView(mButton, lp);
    setContentView(layout);

}
```

I can't see how my layout would effect it, but this is the first time I've had this error, and the first time I tried doing a layout like this. No errors in code, and I tried invalidating caches.

Google hasn't turned up much yet, except for that android.intent.action.MAIN.. any help is appreciated.
Let me know if you need more information about the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity's category should be of type 'Launcher'

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> // This
        </intent-filter>    
</activity>
```